# I can't get the location from locationlistener

Tags: android

I used a Fragment implements LocationListener and i tried to get my current location , but i can't get it successfully. Do i miss something ?

```
public class TrafficInformation extends Fragment implements LocationListener{

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private double myLatitude,myLongitude;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traffic_information_fragment, container, false);
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onResume(); 
 try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;
                //part of android 6.0 permission
                int flag = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                if (flag != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
                } else {
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map

                //i set my current location over here-------------------
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

                //For zooming automatically to the location of the marker

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(16).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

i try to get it from this function:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        myLatitude=location.getLatitude();
        myLongitude=location.getLongitude();
    }
```

i can't get myLatitude and myLongitude location , why?
any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( 
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this)
```

You are only calling

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

This don't request for location updates... just set a pin on your position on the map.

Check here to see how to request current location:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html